# Make upload file label accessible by spacebar and enter

Tags: angular, input, keydown, accessible

I am trying to create a keyboard accessible upload page using angular 2. I am having trouble to enable "Choose a file to upload" using space bar and enter keys. I am able to upload files by clicking the label.

```
<label for="files" > Choose a file to upload </label>
<input type="file" id="files" (click)="upload($event)"/>
```

The display of input is none and I am using the label to allow users to choose which file to upload. I tried onkeypress, keyup and keydown but I am not able to make it keyboard accessible for the label.

Comment: Seems to work fine in https://plnkr.co/edit/UKuSKU5hg9bhakEHR32Y?p=preview with tab and space.

Comment: No. Because I am hiding the default choose file using display:none. I just want users to see Choose a file to upload label.

Comment: How do you expect a useful answer if you omit essential parts of your question. Please provide the code that allows to reproduce your problem and explain the expected behavior.

Comment: I indicated "The display of input is none".

Comment: That's quite hard to interpret without seeing code.

Comment: Basically I am trying to use a button to replace type="file". I just find out I couldn't use label because it doesn't have the functionality as a button. I want to be able to choose a file by just using the keyboard, but not clicking.             `<button>Choose a file to upload</button>
  <input type="file"  name="myFile" (click)="select($event)"/>`
`input {display:none}` @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; I just added a keypress handler to the label to trigger a click on it if the space or enter key is pressed.

[**Here's a working Plunkr.**](https://embed.plnkr.co/2fXrjwikUMdPkxKIEcVc/)

HTML (don't forget the `tabindex="0"`):

```
<label class="btn" for="files" tabindex="0" (keypress)="onUploadLabelClick($event)">Choose a file to upload</label>
<input class="hiddenFileUpload" type="file" id="files" (click)="upload($event)"/>
```

Relevant function:

```
onUploadLabelClick(evt): void {
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 13 || keyCode === 32) {
        $(evt.target).click();
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I use JQuery here, but it's simple enough to do the same with pure JS obviously.